Boost.intrusive push_back using member_hook does not match address of original object
An boost intrusive list that uses list_member_hook<>.
Why does the assertion below fail:
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include <cassert>

using namespace boost::intrusive;
class A
{
public:
    int i_;
    A(int i) : i_(i) {};

    list_member_hook<> m_hook1;
};

typedef list<A, member_hook<A, list_member_hook<>, &A::m_hook1> > List1;

int main()
{
    List1 list1;
    A *a = new A(10);

    list1.push_back(*a);
    assert( a == &list1.back()); //it fails, why? 

     return 0;
}


Did not fail on my machine (godbolt link).  I do not know why it failed on your machine.  I'm using Boost 1.86.

@Eljay: Yes, this could well be the source of the problem.
I'm using boost 1.70 on Embarcadero 12.1 CLang compiler.

The best I can think of is that likely you're seeing the assertion
sotest: /home/sehe/custom/boost/boost/intrusive/detail/generic_hook.hpp:47: void boost::intrusive::detail::destructo
r_impl(Hook&, link_dispatch<boost::intrusive::safe_link>) [with Hook = boost::intrusive::generic_hook<boost::intrusi
ve::CircularListAlgorithms, boost::intrusive::list_node_traits<void*>, boost::intrusive::member_tag, boost::intrusiv
e::safe_link, boost::intrusive::NoBaseHookId>]: Assertion `!hook.is_linked()' failed.

I get this same assertion. The failure happens because when a is destructed before the list.
Reproducing The Assertion
Simplifying the example and making it so that it doesn't rely on a memory leak:
Live On Coliru
#undef NDEBUG
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include <cassert>

namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

class A {
    [[maybe_unused]] int i_;

  public:
    A(int i) : i_(i) {};

    bi::list_member_hook<> m_hook{};
};

using List = bi::list<A, bi::member_hook<A, bi::list_member_hook<>, &A::m_hook>>;

int main() {
    List list;
    A    a(10);
    list.push_back(a);
    assert(&a == &list.back());
}

Fixing It
In this simple example, simply switching declaration order fixes it:
int main() {
    A    a(10);
    List list;
    list.push_back(a);
    assert(&a == &list.back());
}


The instance of A must be in the heap, not a local object in main, that is the requirement.

It's not a requirement for Boost Intrusive at all. Anyways, it was just the simplest way to demonstrate a way where you could get a confusing assertion with very similar code. It makes no difference whether it's on the heap: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3909692818e0582c vs https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3aa950b13466e9d3

Once again I do not want a to a local  object.
Consider this:
void AddToList( List1& list1 ) {     A a(10); // This has to be in the heap     list1.push_back(a); } int main() {     List1 list1;     AddToList( list1 ); } 
The program would crash.

@AlexNet Of course. Why don't you edit your question code to match what you actually have and reproduces the error?

See @Eljay above.

You think I don't read the comments? Eljay ALSO notes that your question code does not reproduce an error. I'm not going to split hairs about the presence of the memory leak if the code doesn't actually demonstrate your problem anyways.

It motivated me to expand my root volume. I made sure nothing changes with clang-12 and boost 1.70.0. https://i.imgur.com/LHYRwqs.png. Of course, your question code also runs cleanly. I do note that if you use the pattern from your comment you basically guarantee the wrong order of destruction, unless you are really doing element-by-element cleanup manually (or just leak all the elements)
